# How I can add Local Storage to my React.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got an app - todo list with comments that store different items such as list items, comments, number of comments etc.

Can you help me to add localStorage to my app so all the items could be saved to the localStorage?

I've read an article that said that we need to path 2 variables: key and object. How could I pass the entire state with all items?

Here is the code:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ListInput from './components/listInput'
import ListItem from './components/listItem'
import SideBar from './components/sideBar'
import CommentsSection from './components/commentsSection'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [
        {
          id: 1, 
          title: 'First item',
          commentsCount: 0,
          comments: [],
          displayComment: false
        },
        {
          id: 2, 
          title: 'Second item',
          commentsCount: 0,
          comments: [],
          displayComment: false
        },
        {
          id: 3, 
          title: 'Third item',
          commentsCount: 0,
          comments: [],
          displayComment: false
        },
      ],
      activeItem: {},
      isHidden: true
    }
  }
  // Add new item to the list
  addItem = inputText => {
    let itemsCopy = this.state.items.slice();
    itemsCopy.push({id: this.state.items.length + 1, title: inputText, commentsCount: 0, comments: [], displayComment: false});

    this.setState({
      items: itemsCopy,
    })
  }
  // Remove the item from the list: check if the clicked button id is match 
  removeItem = id =>
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.filter((item, index) => item.id !== id)
    })

  addComment = (inputComment) => {
    // find item with id passed and select its comments array
     const commentCopy = this.state.items.map(item => {
       if (item.id === this.state.activeItem.id) {
         return {
           ...item, 
           commentsCount: item.comments.length + 1,
           comments: item.comments.concat({id: item.comments.length + 1, text: inputComment})
          } 
       }
         return item
      });
      this.setState({
       items: commentCopy
     })
   }

  getActiveItem = () => this.state.items.find(item => item.id === this.state.activeItem.id)

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.items.isHidden)
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <SideBar />
        <div className='flex-container'>
          <div className='list-wrapper'>
            <h1>Items</h1>
            <ListInput inputText='' addItem={this.addItem}/>
            <ul>
              {
                this.state.items.map((item) => 
                (<ListItem 
                    item={item} 
                    key={item.id} 
                    id={item.id} 
                    removeItem={this.removeItem} 
                    setActiveComment={() => this.setState({ activeItem: item })} 
                    toggleHidden={() => this.setState({ isHidden: false })}
                  />
                ))
              }
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            {!this.state.isHidden && <CommentsSection 
              addComment={this.addComment} 
              activeItem={this.getActiveItem()}
            />}
          </div>  
        </div>  
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**commentSection.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import CommentInput from './commentInput'
import CommentsItem from './commentsItem'
import './commentsSection.css';

export default class CommentsSection extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};
    }

    handleChange = event => this.setState({value: event.target.value})

    handleEnter = event => {
        if (event.charCode === 13 && event.ctrlKey) {
            console.log(this.state, this.props)
            this.addComment(this.state.value)
        } 
    }    

    addComment = comment => {
        console.log(this.props.activeComment)
         // Ensure the comment text isn't empty
        if (comment.length > 0) {
          this.props.addComment(comment);
          this.setState({value: ''});
        }   
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='component-section'>
                <h1>{this.props.activeItem && this.props.activeItem.title}</h1>
                <ul>
                { this.props.activeItem &&
                    this.props.activeItem.comments.map((comment) => <p key={comment.id}>{comment.text}</p>)
                }
                </ul>
                {/*<CommentsItem />*/}
                {/*<CommentInput addComment={this.addComment}/>*/}
                <div className='comment-input'>
                    <input type='text' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onKeyPress={this.handleEnter}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**listInput.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './listInput.css'

export default class ListInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: this.props.inputText};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = event => this.setState({value: event.target.value})

    addItem(item) {
        // Ensure the todo text isn't empty
        if (item.length > 0) {
          this.props.addItem(item);
          this.setState({value: ''});
        }   
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className='list-input'>
            <input type='text' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder={'Type name here...'}/>
            <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={() => this.addItem(this.state.value)}>Add new</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **A Simple Explanation:**

localStorage has two important methods:

- `localStorage.setItem(*name*,*string value*)`

  - The parameter `name` is simply the key you wish to store in Storage to easily reference the data.
  - The parameter `string value` is simply the value you wish to store in Storage under the `key/name`. The important thing is that it **must** be a string. `localStorage` is **unable** to store **Arrays and/or Objects**
- `localStorage.getItem(*name*)`

  - The only parameter necessary is the `name` which is the previously set `name` given to `setItem`.
  - If the `key/name` doesn't exist within `localStorage` it returns **null**, if it *does* exist it returns the **string value**.

Why are these things important? State is an **Object**. Let's create a small version:

```
let state = { name: "zak" };
```

As previously stated, you **cannot** store anything other than a **string** within `localStorage`. So what do we do then? We want to store state, right? Well... we have to transpose our Object *into* a **string**.

We can do this using the `JSON` methods:

- `JSON.stringify(**object or array**)`

  - This will simply take any passed in **object or array** and transform it into a **string**.
- `JSON.parse(**string**)`

  - This will take any **string** and try to re-evaluate it using JavaScript to turn it back into an **Object** or **Array**.

We have a state **Object** that we need to turn into a **string** before we can save it using `localStorage.setItem`. For this we use `JSON.stringify`.

When using `localStorage.getItem`, we'll receive a representation of the state object as a **string** that we need to turn into a state **object** before we can use it in our application. For this we use `JSON.parse`.

---

**A code example of SAVING:**

```
let state = { name: "zak" };

let state_string = JSON.stringify(state); 

localStorage.setItem("my_saved_state", state_string);
```

The above will take state, turn it into a string and save it. To do the reverse we simply have to get the **string** and turn it back into an **object**.

---

**A code example of LOADING:**

```
let state = { name: "zak" };

let state_string = JSON.stringify(state); 

localStorage.setItem("my_saved_state", state_string);

let returned_state_string = localStorage.getItem("my_saved_state");

let returned_state_object = JSON.parse(returned_state_string);
```

The result of the above is:

```
console.log(returned_state_object); // { name: "zak" }
console.log(state); // { name: "zak" }
```

As you can see, you've effectively **saved** and **loaded** from `localStorage`.

---

### **A more thorough and in-depth Explanation:**

Use `setItem` and `getItem` methods of the `localStorage` API.

You can then save using a `name` and a stringified Object through `JSON.stringify`. This is important because the `storage api` **only** allows the saving of strings. **No object literals, no arrays, etc.**

You can then load by referencing that `name` and parsing the returned String through `JSON.parse`. This will effectively rehydrate a string back to it's original, object/array form.

**Important Note**: Any references within an Object or Array that is stored within `state` **will break** upon transposing to a string. Obviously a string can't be a reference, so this makes sense. To get around this you could create a parser to redesign the references, but that's out of the scope of this answer.

---

A bit of an opinion, I'll admit, but a well regarded one I believe, is that it's best to use functions when working with the Storage API as it can make coding much clearer. Below is an example of saving state, loading state, and testing that the saved and loaded state are the same to prove the concept.

**Important Note:** you'll notice that in the load function we first receive the data in `raw_data` - this is because if the key doesn't happen to exist(a.e. the first time you run the program, you won't have saved data) it will return `null`. It's a simple sanity check that will return an empty object if none exists - in your case you may want to throw an error instead, but it's up to you.

*StackOverflow does not allow use of storage, it appears, so if you'd like to see a running version please take a look at this accompanying [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jkzt4p6/1/)*

```
let state = {
  items: [{
      id: 1,
      title: 'First item',
      commentsCount: 0,
      comments: [],
      displayComment: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Second item',
      commentsCount: 0,
      comments: [],
      displayComment: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Third item',
      commentsCount: 0,
      comments: [],
      displayComment: false
    },
  ],
  activeItem: {},
  isHidden: true
}


function saveAs(name, state_obj) {
  let data = JSON.stringify(state_obj);
  localStorage.setItem(name, data);
  console.log("saved!");
}

function loadFrom(name) {
  let raw_data, data;
  raw_data = localStorage.getItem(name);
  if (!raw_data) return {};
  data = JSON.parse(raw_data);
  return data;
}

function test(_old, _new) {
return JSON.stringify(_old) === JSON.stringify(_new);
}

saveAs("my_saved_state", state);
let myNewState = loadFrom("my_saved_state");

console.log( test(state, myNewState) ? "old and new are the same!" : "old and new are different" );
```

Comment: thank you, but I still don't understand, could you provide me with a small example?
if I want to pass the entire state to the localStorage what will be the key?

Comment: @Leocete I edited the above. Hopefully that helps make it really clear.

Comment: it is the best explanation on localStorage concept I've ever read :-) thank you 

but talking about my app, where should I add 

`localStorage.setItem('storage-items', JSON.stringify(items))` ?

Comment: sorry, I'm pretty new to programming

Comment: @Leocete We've all been there. Unfortunately I don't know exactly, it depends when you want to save your state in storage. You can put it into an event handler, or into a React lifecycle method, it's kind of your call. You may want to look more into the React API to give yourself a better idea of when you'd like to do so.

Answer (score 1):

React makes it pretty easy.

```
// setter
localStorage.setItem('myData', data);

// getter
localStorage.getItem('myData');
```

You automatically get access to the `localStorage` object through the browser. Just keep in mind that `.setItem` does not have a return value, so just use it synchronously.

Comment: Yes, I've read this in different articles, but I don't understand what kind of data I should pass in my example?

Comment: something like this?


`localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items))`